# paper-input change vs value-changed

Tags: polymer-2.x

can anyone please explain the difference between `change` and `value-changed` events for polymer's `paper-input` element? The docs mentioned [here](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/behaviors/Polymer.PaperInputBehavior) do not explain this difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change` occurs when `paper-input` loses focus and if there is any
   changes in the value.

`value-changed` occurs  when user presses a key in `paper-input` to change the value.

Demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7eU7XGwfmRt1LgW1hbRz?p=preview).

Comment: So, `change` is same as `blur` event? If yes, has the `blur` event been removed from `paper-input`?

Comment: `blur` has not been removed. `paper-input` is extending `HTMLElement` which means that all the features will be there. `change` occurs when there is `blur` plus any changes in the value.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. One more query: The `Event` object that I get in the event listener for `change` has `currentTarget` set as `null`. Is there any way to get the `paper-input` element in the event handler?

Comment: Use `e.target`. To get the value you can simple do `e.target.value`.